# How to create grouped bar plot instead of facet_wrap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that has three categorical variables. I know how to use ggplot geom_bar to create a bar plot and facet_wrap. But I want the bars to be grouped by the third categorical variable rather than wrapped. See the plot below. I want the "fall" and "winter" facets to be on top of each other. For example, I want the "fall" results in Grade 10 to be below the "winter" results within one grid. Perhaps I need to structure my data differently.

```
tmp = data.frame(Grade = rep(1:10, each = 6),
                 Placement = as.factor(rep(1:5, times = 6)),
                 Window = rep(c("fall", "winter"), times = 15),
                 Percent = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 20))

ggplot(data = tmp, 
       aes(x = Grade, y = Percent, fill = Placement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Window)) +
 coord_flip() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Grade",
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percent",
                     limits = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

I'd like it to look more like this:

[image]

Comment: You can use Window on the x-axis, then `facet_grid(vars(Grade), scales = "free_y", switch = "y")` gets you most of the way there. I'm confused by the groupings, though, since the colors that come from your code don't seem to correspond to the color groupings in the example of what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your original dataframe to have percentages directly and to have the correct number of placements per grade (you had 6 "slots" per grade, but placements only from 1 to 5).

Use `facet_grid()` instead of `facet_wrap()`.
Also, the `x` axis should be `Window` and the facets are the `Grade` variable.

```
tmp <- data.frame(Grade = as.factor(rep(1:10, each = 6)),
                  Placement = as.factor(rep(1:6, times = 10)),
                  Window = rep(c("fall", "winter"), times = 15),
                  Percent = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 20) / 100)

ggplot(data = tmp, aes(x = Window, y = Percent, fill = Placement)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(Grade~., labeller = label_both, switch = "y") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Percent, accuracy = 1)), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is different than what you had, but much closer to the picture you showed:

```
ggplot(data = tmp, 
       aes(x = Window, y = Percent, fill = Placement)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity",position = "fill") +
  facet_wrap(~Grade, scales = "free_y", switch = "y", nrow = 10) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost like in the picture (I can't find how to fuse all "Grade" labels on top of the `facet_wrap`). I did not change the color pattern but it could be easily done using `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 
tmp %>% arrange(desc(Grade)) %>% mutate(Grade2 = paste("Grade",Grade)) %>%
  mutate(Grade2 = factor(Grade2, unique(Grade2))) %>%
  ggplot( 
       aes(x = Window, y = Percent, fill = Placement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percent",
                     limits = c(0, 100))+
  facet_wrap(Grade2~Window, scales = "free_y",strip.position = "left", ncol = 1)+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percent,2),"%")),  
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.8), size = 2)+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        panel.margin.y = unit(-0.25, "lines"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`facet_grid` probably gives better results than `facet_wrap` that some other answers used

```
tmp$Grade = factor(paste('Grade', tmp$Grade), levels = paste('Grade', 1:10))
ggplot(data = tmp, aes(x = Window, y = Percent, fill = Placement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(Grade~., switch = 'y') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

If you want to remove the gaps between facets, you can use

```
theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0,'npc'))
```